# How can this prep. phrase be parsed?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> Another war began right there. Captain Roque Carnicero and his six men
>   left **with Colonel Aureliano Buendia to free the revolutionary
>   general Victorio Medina**, who had been condemned to death in
>   Riohacha. (One Hundred Years of Solitude, tr. by Gregory Rabassa)

Does the prepositional phrase take a role of adverbial; in the phrase, ‘Colonel Aureliano Buendia’ is a semantic subject, and ‘to free the revolutionary general Victorio Medina’ the predicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *with ...* and *to free ...* phrases are distinct.

- The *with* phrase says that Capt. Carnicero and his men accompanied Col. Buendia (and presumably were under his command).
- the *to free ...* phrase is an infinitive of purpose: it names the goal of the expedition, freeing Medina.

Both phrases are adverbial or adsentential, but they describe different phases of the action.